# О причастии и прилагательном на -мый

Tags: частица-не, прилагательные, причастия

Правильно ли я рассуждаю?

**Невпускаемые в зал люди толпятся у входа.**
Впускать – глагол несовершенного вида, переходный. Нет пояснительного слова в творительном падеже, значит, это прилагательное, пишем с НЕ слитно.

**Не впускаемые дежурным в зал люди толпятся у входа.**
Так как есть пояснительное слово в творительном падеже, то это причастие и пишем его с НЕ раздельно.

И второй вопрос: Можно ли при глаголе в прошедшем времени (толпились) употреблять причастие настоящего времени?

**Невпускаемые в зал люди толпились у входа.**

Answer (score 2):

Не думаю, что это верный путь. А есть ли такое прилагательное - невпускаемый? Попробуйте употребить его отдельно, без зависимых слов. Каким синонимом его можно заменить? Я такого не знаю. Это явно причастие и здесь просится деятель - субъект, совершаемый действие. Кто-то же их не впускает? Это причастие по главному признаку - обозначает непостоянный признак по действию, совершаемому кем-то в настоящее время. Не впускаемые-не впущенные кем-то. Категории времени у прилагательного нет.

Не впускаемые в зал люди толпились у входа.-нежелательное употребление глагольных форм настоящего и прошедшего времени, желательно соблюдать видо-временную соотнесённость.

Answer (score 1):

Набираю в поисковике слово ***впускаемый***, мне предлагают заменить его на **выпускаемый**, а  ***невпускаемый*** Яндекс, недолго думая,  определяет как  опечатку. В Нацкрпусе нашелся "**впускаемый в домну газ**" и небезызвестный гражданин N, ***не впускаемый*** в токарню еще в 18 веке.

Раньше не было Интернета, и **люди придумывали учебные примеры сами.** Примеры получались плохими, но у них не было другого выхода. Когда в нашу жизнь вошел  Интернет (и Нацкорпус), появилась возможность работать с живыми текстами, но люди по привычке (или по другой причине) **по-прежнему придумывают учебные примеры.**

Учиться по таким примерам очень трудно, а выучиться практически невозможно. Я бы запретила печатать в учебниках "неживые тексты": придуманные слова, неестественные сочетания и предложения.

**И конечно, не имеет смысла отвечать на вопросы с такими примерами.**